What is an equivalent of in operator for 2D Numpy array?
Using Python lists:
a = [[0, 1], [3, 4]]
b = [0, 2]
print(b in a)

I'm getting False as an output, but with Numpy arrays:
a = np.array([[0, 1], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([0, 2])
print(b in a)

I'm getting True as an output. What is an equivalent of in operator above for 2D Numpy arrays?

In the NumPy array case, b in a is interpreted as checking if any element of b is in a, rather than checking for the presence of b as a whole array.
You can use the numpy.all function along with numpy.any to compare rows:
a = np.array([[0, 1], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([0, 2])

is_row_present = np.any(np.all(a == b, axis=1))
print(is_row_present)
>>> False


In general, if you have a N-dim haystack, and a (N-1)-dim needle and want to find all locations where the needle occurs in the haystack you can compare with == broadcasting the needle and then, reduce with all on all dimensions except the first:
(haystack == needle).all(axis=tuple(range(1, haystack.ndim)))

If you want to know if there are any matches, simply append .any() to the above expression.

This code should be one solution that works similar to in for python's lists:
(a == b).all(1).any()

Alternatively, you can replace (a == b) with numpy.isin(a, b).
Explanation
The first part, (a == b), returns this array:
>>> a = numpy.array([[0, 1], [3, 4]])
>>> b = numpy.array([0, 2])
>>> a == b
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False]])

The True represents the matching 0 here.
When b is part of a, the result may look like this:
>>> a = numpy.array([[0, 1], [3, 4]])
>>> b = numpy.array([3, 4])
>>> a == b
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True]])

So all booleans in one row have to be True.
To check this, we call all(axis=1). This returns a boolean for each column.
>>> a = numpy.array([[0, 1], [3, 4]])
>>> b = numpy.array([0, 2])
>>> (a == b).all(1)
array([False,  False])
>>> b = numpy.array([3, 4])
>>> (a == b).all(1)
array([False,  True])

And finally we call any() to check if there are any occurrences.
Counting occurrences and finding the index
Note that you can also count the occurrences or find the first index by replacing any() with other functions.

To count the occurrences use sum().
To find the first index use argmax(). Keep in mind that argmax() returns 0 if no occurrence is found.


According to this answer, this would be the best option:
a = np.array([[0, 1], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([0, 2])

any(np.equal(a, b).all(1))


You can do this way:
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([0, 2])

result = any((b == x).all() for x in a)
print(result) # Output : False

